# Why ul > li (selector) doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

ul > li (selector) doesn't work. What am I missing here?

```css
/* Part 1 */
ul > li{
  margin-top:30px;
}

/* Part 2 */
/* ul .test{
  margin-top:30px;
} */
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="test">item1</li>
<ul>
  <li>subitem1</li>
  <li>subitem2</li>
</ul>
<li class="test">item2</li>
<li class="test">item3</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gy5r3noh/

Shouldn't Part 1 and Part 2 in css be equal? But It isn't. ul > li should select all li children of ul (like class=test I created), but it doesn't work by ul > li.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` can't be a child of a `<ul>`

Comment: How is it not working? It's applying a 30px margin to every li, because every li is a child of its parent ul. No?

Comment: not equal. the 2nd targets only the element with class "test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that your HTML is invalid [as j08691 has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662996/why-ul-li-selector-doesnt-work/43663104#comment74372850_43662996), and assuming your inner `ul` is intended to be wrapped in a `li` element:

1. `ul > li` selects any `li` element which is a child of any `ul` element.
2. `ul .test` selects any element with a class of "test" contained within any `ul` element.

One and two give different results with your HTML structure because your nested `ul` does not contain `li` elements with a class of "test". Example one applies to both the outer and inner `ul` elements, whereas example two only affects the `li` elements with a class of "test" (which there are none of within your nested `ul`).

Answer (score 0):

you HTML is invalid, `ul` can't have `ul` as direct child

```css
ul > .test {
  margin-top: 30px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="test">item1
    <ul>
      <li>subitem1</li>
      <li>subitem2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="test">item2</li>
  <li class="test">item3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That changes nothing, though.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Part 1 */
ul > li{
  margin-top:30px;
}

/* Part 2 */
/* ul .test{
  margin-top:30px;
} */
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="test">item1</li>
<ul>
  <li>subitem1</li>
  <li>subitem2</li>
</ul>
<li class="test">item2</li>
<li class="test">item3</li>
</ul>
```

Here, Html Should be like,

```
<ul>
<li class="test">item1
  <ul>
    <li>subitem1</li>
    <li>subitem2</li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="test">item2</li>
<li class="test">item3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How is this different from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43663028/578411

Comment: Its same, Nothing different. I just created Html structure,

Comment: There is no point in having answers that don't add anything new. We want (new) answers to add value, not repeat what is already there.

Comment: Yes, I know and I try to educate you a bit how you can improve. Being open for advice is a good starting point ;)  Enjoy your stay on Stack Overflow. If you need a bit extra guidance remember we have an [help]