# CSS selector $parent > $child selects all <li> child elements in nested lists

Tags: css

The css selector $parent > $immediateChild is not working for nested lists.
Only the direct `<li>` of the level-1 list should be red, but the selector selects all `<li>` in all nested lists.

```css
ul.level-1 > li
{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="level-1">
    <li>Level 1
      <ul>
          <li>Level 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662996/why-ul-li-selector-doesnt-work) and it states that the second `<ul>` needs to be in the `<li>` of the first  to have valid html. I did that but it's not working.

/EDIT: I just transformed my nested list to `<div>`s instead like before. It's a menu with a submenu and sub-submenu. The nested list is hard to address via CSS and there were also issues with my flexbox submenu.

So, I can't recommend doing menus with a (nested) list because all styles are natively inherited to all childs which is probably not what you want. The accepted answer would solve this particular problem, though.

Comment: `ul.level-1 > li` works as you expected. It's just that an element's `color` affect all its descendants'.

Comment: Okay, so this is special for text styles? `padding` etc. is working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles automatically get applied ("inherited") to descendants of targeted children, just like in your example.

If you want the second layer of `li` elements to e.g. have black text color, you have to target them again:

```css
ul.level-1 > li
{
    color: red;
}
ul.level-1 > li > ul > li
{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="level-1">
    <li>Level 1 - 1 child
      <ul>
          <li>Level 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1 - no children</li>
    <li>Level 1 - 1+ children
      <ul>
          <li>Level 2</li>
          <li>Level 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thought about that, but... this is intendent to do it like this? /edit: I have nested until level 3, so I can still handle it, so I probably will do that

Comment: @ChrostipSchaejn A generic solution would be `li { color: black; } li:not(li li) { color: red; }`.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of styles are inherited down to the child elements of the element you style.

If the default value of an CSS property is `inherit`, it uses the value the parent has set for that property.

Styling the second `ul` would already be enough to change the color.

```css
ul.level-1 > li
{
    color: red;
}

    ul.level-1 > li > ul
    {
        color: green;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="level-1">
    <li>Level 1
      <ul>
          <li>Level 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Another way to fix the problem is to reset the color:

```
color: initial;
```

This would also make the text color revert to the original (black in most of the cases).

[This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5612360/1336174) has a list of inherited properties.

[web.dev](https://web.dev/learn/css/inheritance/) also has some information about it.